# using Checkov: How can I check the configuration for terraform backend block

Tags: terraform, checkov

Any help appreciated.
Just started using checkov custom policies for terraform.
I want to enforce a check on the backend configuration, and what I am trying to enforce is value for credentials attribute should start with "#{" , Is it possible?

contents of backend.tf

```
    terraform {
     backend "gcs" {
      bucket = "odeploy"
      prefix = "dev"
      credentials = "#{gcpcred.JsonKey | FromBase64 | JsonEscape}"
     }
    }
```

Contents of Customcheck.yaml

```
    metadata:
     name: "Check that the credentials in backend block starts with #{"
     id: "CKV2_GOOGLE_3"
     category: "GENERAL_SECURITY"
    definition:
     cond_type: "attribute"
     resource_types:
     - terraform.backend # other variation i have tried are "terraform", "backend.gcs"
     attribute: "backend.*.credentials" # also tried "backend.gcs.credentials"/"credentials"
     operator: starting_with
     value: "#{"
```

Output:
[image]

---

The following however works- contents of customcheck2.yaml

```
    metadata:
      name: "Check that the credentials in provider block starts with #{"
      id: "CKV2_GOOGLE_1"
      category: "GENERAL_SECURITY"
    scope:
      provider: google
    definition:
      cond_type: "attribute"
      resource_types: 
        - provider.google
      attribute: "credentials"
      operator: starting_with
      value: "#{"
```

contents of provider.tf

```
    provider "google" {
      project = "some-project"
      region  = "us-east4"
      zone    = "us-east4-c"
      credentials = "#{gcpcred.JsonKey | FromBase64 | JsonEscape}"
    }
```

output:

[image]

NOTE: output images are part of the same output. I have split it into two images and shared separately above.

Answer (score 0):

Just heard back from **bridgecrewio/checkov** team:
***this is currently not possible and there is no plan on adding such a capability anytime soon.***

[image]

[Checkov github issue link](https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov/issues/5198)

Comment: Please share the link too